# Small image slider script coughing up untyped exception error

Tags: javascript, html

I am really a beginner at javascript and wanted to create a small image slider. I have used  setInterval to delay the loading so that it would create a slider effect.  But somehow the images are not sliding and I have a hinch that the problem lies in the loop. I have already looked up at some options and am asking here as a last option. Thanks in advance.

```
<!Doctype html>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <head>

<title>Simple Image Slider</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   var counter=0;
    var images=new Array['download.jpg','images (1).jpg','images.jpg'];

       function start(){

    setInterval("slide()",2000);
      }

    function slide(){
    for(counter=0;counter<images.length;counter++)
document.getElementById('mageslide').src=images[counter];
   }
 </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
     </head>
     <body>
<div id="wrapper">
      <div class="slider" onload="start()">
          <img src="images.jpg" id="mageslide"></img>
       </div>
      **strong text** </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What exactly are you gonna do!!! You want to change the image in mageslide after every interval???

Comment: Then there is problem in your code! lemme post it for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `slide()` function is wrong, you're supposed to iterate one image per interval, not all images in one interval iteration, try this fixed version:

```
function slide(){
   window.counter++;
   if (window.counter >= window.images.length) {
      window.counter = 0;
   }
   document.getElementById('mageslide').src=window.images[window.counter];
}
```

Comment: @Bazinga777 I'm glad this worked for you, you now have enough reputation to make upvotes, so consider upvoting my answer (up arrow) if you are happy with it :-)

Answer (score 0):

you cant just change the value, intead of this, try to change the innerhtml, dinamically inserting a img src

`document.getElementById('mageslide').innerHTML='<img src="'+images[counter]+'">'` something like this

edit: assuming the mageslide is a div or something

Answer (score 0):

```
<!Doctype html>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <head>

<title>Simple Image Slider</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

   var images=new Array['download.jpg','images (1).jpg','images.jpg'];
   var counter;

       function start(){
           for(counter=0;counter<images.length;counter++) {
               setInterval("slide()",2000);
           }
       }

    function slide(){
       images[counter].onload = function() {
       document.getElementById('mageslide').src=images[counter];
       }
    }
 </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
     </head>
     <body>
<div id="wrapper">
      <div class="slider" onload="start()">
          <img src="images.jpg" id="mageslide"></img>
       </div>
      **strong text** </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```